# PCI-DSS, what is the best distro?

Tags: linux, pci-dss, pci-scope

What is the best distro of Linux to get PCI-DSS compliant?

I am using Debian 8 because I think Debian is one of the most stable versions, but it seems not to be enough, I am struggling with a lot of vulnerabilities.

Furthermore, if anyone could post what would be better if apache vs nginx in combination with the chosen distro I will really appreciated that.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever version you decide to use you will have to implement a formal lock-down and security maintenance programme for your systems and there won't be much difference between the major versions (Centos, Debian or Ubuntu for example). They all need careful install, lock-down, and patching/monitoring/managing.

I have a number of clients who successfully use Centos and Ubuntu (!4.10 LTS) which, together with appropriate configuration, patching, and montitoring regimes pass level 1 PCS-DSS audit each year without issue.

Apache and Nginx will both be fine for PCI-DSS applications as long as they are also patched, configured securely and monitored etc. It's not really the software (within reason) but the way you use them that's important to PCI.

Comment: Thx, I really appreciate your answer. I think, got success on the test is going to be a nightmare anyway.

Comment: I'd recommend against using RHEL or CentOS because the practice of back porting instead of upgrading to the latest packages leads to an enormous amount of time spent on disputing the scan results.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your process to become PCI-DSS compliant by downloading the standard from [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/pci_dss.shtml)

After this its wise to visit Center for Internet Security ([CIS](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=default)) to download some benchmark about your distribution

And in internet you can find a lot of documents, discussion your case, for example [this](http://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/7506-PCI-DSS-from-a-Linux-SysAdmins-Perspective.html)

P.S. My humble opinion is to choose some commercial distribution as RHEL or SuSE to get professional support and assistance when implement PCI-DSS

Comment: Well, the true is that I got myself involved in this process because in my current company we have done a kind of customer portal in which we can get payments thought the platform (what I have created more a third party provider).  At the beginning, we filled a kind of questionnaire full of confusing questions and then I need to pass a test. This test, is showing more than 200 hundreds vulnerabilities. I just solved 100 hundred but, in my opinion, it will be really hard pass it with success. Thx, I appreciate it

Comment: Yep, the process is not easy, but if you read careful PCI documentation and map the requirements to real OS actions is not so heavy process (but it take time)